SQL Views as the Read Model of the CQRS Architecture
I am just thinking about the approach when a set of SQL Views can act as the Read Model in CQRS. In this case the conversion between an HTTP and SQL can be dynamically generated. All you need is to define a set of URLs and map them onto the views. For instance, if you have a couple of tables Book and Author, and written SQL code for the view VBook
select t1.id,
       t1.name,      
       t2.name as authorName
  from Book   t1
  join Author t2 on t2.id = t1.author

you just somehow map /api/books/{id} onto VBook. After that you can use the following HTTP requests:

/api/books/1
/api/books?authorName=John*
/api/books?id=1,2,3

All these requests will be automatically converted into the following SQL queries:

select * from VBook where id = 1
select * from VBook where authorName like 'John%'
select * from VBook where id in (1, 2, 3)

How does this idea sound for you? Maybe you know some libraries with similar functionality for Java?

It doesn't make too much sense. CQRS is about combining data that resides in separated databases, for viewing purposes. The whole point is to avoid creating a SQL view that spans more than a single database.

I am absolutely agree that a canonical version of the CQRS approach segregates read and write databases. However, when a separate database does not act a significant role (event more: it increases complexity) in your application, you may follow only some of rules of CQRS. In this scenario, you may use a single database for both read and write streams. Due to writing a code for a database View is simpler than writing a chain of Java classes from HTTP-controller to a DAO, so this idea was born in my head.

in my experience the typical issues with views is that they hide the complexity of the data and rookie developers end up using them without understanding the cost of them. For example, if a view joins 10 tables, then a rookie dev may use it when it needs data from two tables only, since "it's already there". Queries become havier than necessary.
